# Flash Questions

Tags: flash

I am new to flash, but I want to learn!

I have questions:

1. In Flash you can define the interface with some XML like:

?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
txtPage>
    pageTitle>indie Blog</b>]]>
    pageTxt>
        page text
    /pageTxt>
/txtPage>"

How can I add Hyperlinks? Simply putting it inbetween the  doesn't render in the movie.

2. Can Flash access MySQL databases and display data? (like loop through a record set?)
3. Is it possible to have flash call an ajax-y type page and render it and allow users to click, etc, etc?

-Jason

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly new here myself, but in general you should try to keep it to one actual question per question. Your title is enough to have many of the mods here just close your question for "Not being a question".

That being said, I'll try to help out... First, you can use XML in Flash, but unless you're using Flex you don't directly define the UI using XML. With Flex you're using MXML which has it's own special tags. With Flash you'll need to load the XML and then loop through it to build whatever you're trying to build.

Secondly, yes, Flash can work with databases, just not directly. Something on the client (like Flash or JS) shouldn't talk to a database directly. Instead it should talk through some middleware like PHP or ASP.net. You can talk between middleware and Flash in many different ways - standard GET/POST, XML, JSON, and a Flash specific data exchange format called AMF - all are supported by PHP.

Finally Flash can not load and render HTML on it's own unless you're deploying it to the desktop using Adobe AIR. Flash can talk to an HTML page it's rendered in however. For that you'll use the ExternalInterface class.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Yes](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/53/1/Integrating-Flash-and-mySQL/Page1.html) you can store the results in an ArrayCollection and loop through it (actionscript 3)
2. Not sure I'm following this question. You just want flash to redirect the user to an Ajax page?

   navigateToURL(new URLRequest('page.html'),'_self')

Answer (score 0):

I suggest picking up a tutorial book on Flash and working through that. There is a wide selection to choose from and they will likely provide a better start than asking questions on StackOverflow.

Branden's answers address your direct issues however a strong base in Flash is required before delving into things such as database interactions.

If you aren't sure you want to invest, you can also find online tutorials for free.

Best of Luck!